# How to sort the same data twice by createdAt and updatedAt fields on Eloquent

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, slim

For example, think like we have a data:

### ID   created_at           updated_at

**16**    2019-07-07 12:00:00    2019-07-07 12:30:00

**17**    2019-07-07 14:00:00    2019-07-07 15:45:00

**18**    2019-07-07 15:00:00    2019-07-07 15:30:00

### I want to sort it like this:

**16** is created

**16** is updated

**17** is created

**18** is created

**18** is updated

**17** is updated

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name in model;

Example;

```
const CREATED_AT = 'in';
const UPDATED_AT = 'out';
```

Comment: Yusuf, tarih bazlı sıralamaya çalışıyorum. Sorunum isimlendirme ile ilgili değil. Oluşturulma veya güncellenme tarihlerini farklı ele almaya çalışıyorum.

Comment: O halde created_at ve updated_at alanlarını collection olarak bir değişkene atayıp sortBy() ile tarihe göre sıralatabilirsiniz.